# An integral that involves an infinite sum and complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Lets say I got a function like this:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (z-1-i)^n$$
Assume that $f(z)$ is meromorphic, evaluate $\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)e^{ix}dx$. I guess that the trick is probably to turn the stuff inside that bracket to some exponentials first, then try to "remove" the dummy variable (i.e. n) from the integral. I am stuck in question and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: $f(z)$ is a power series with center $1+i$ and radius of convergence $1$. So, $f(x)$ is not defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Find $f$ on the disc of convergence by summing the power series, extend it to the plane meromorphically using the formula obtained and then see what integral you get